# Rails: Accessing models in helpers - right or wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, view-helpers

My colleague has written a lot of code where models are accessed from view helpers. Is it a good or bad practice?

P.S. I know that similar question exists somewhere on Stackoverflow - Google finds it, but links are outdated.

Comment: It's not really wrong but it means you need presenters which are far more appropriate.

Comment: It's better than using the models directly in the view. But yeah like @apneadiving said. Presenters or decorators are the way to go.